# Saving a Numpy array as an image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a matrix in the type of a Numpy array.  How would I write it to disk it as an image?  Any format works (png, jpeg, bmp...).  One important constraint is that PIL is not present.

Comment: I'd just like to note that some of the answers below, and surely some of the people coming and finding this question, do not meet the constraint listed above of being _without_ [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  Since some askers and some answers both avoid that constraint, I encourage anyone who's here and doesn't mind having PIL to look below, and any non-PIL answers (new or old) to mention that they're a PIL-is-used type of answer, to distinguish themselves from answers meeting the original constraint.

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480297/viewing-npy-images

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [PyPNG](https://github.com/drj11/pypng/). It's a pure Python (no dependencies) open source PNG encoder/decoder and it [supports](https://pypng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ex.html#numpy) writing NumPy arrays as images.

Comment: Remember to scale the values to the right range for PNG, usually 0..255. The value ranges in neural networks are frequently 0..1 or -1..1.

Comment: PyPNG is pure Python, which reduces its external dependencies, but makes it much slower than PIL and its derived classes. For example, saving a 3000x4000 image on my machine took 4.05 seconds with PyPNG but only 0.59 seconds with scipy.misc.imsave (6x faster).

Comment: @TomášGavenčiak - scipy.misc.imsave is now deprecated in the newer versions of Scipy. An alternative a few comments below is to use imageio.imwrite('image_file.jpg', array)

Answer (score 453):

Using [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), save a NumPy array `arr` by doing:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
im.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

See the docs for [available data formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html), including JPEG, PNG, and so on.

Comment: Image is a module of PIL. Do "print Image.__file__"

Comment: Very helpful for those of us who wandered here and do have PIL - I think I'll use `from PIL import Image` to keep it clear...

Comment: If you've got an RGB image, you can get the image using im = Image.fromarray(A).convert('RGB')
More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711880/pil-using-fromarray-with-binary-data-and-writing-coloured-text

Comment: Using third axis of an array of uint8 to code RGB works with this method. Module PIL can be installed using "pip install pillow".

Comment: PIL is python 2 only I think?

Comment: @HughPerkins PIL is supported in Python 3 as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179948

Comment: it's a perfect answer

Comment: @Zvika this method distorts images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293077/why-is-pils-image-fromarray-distorting-my-image-color

Comment: @Ludovico Verniani It does not distort images, but it does use a somewhat uncommon color encoding in which the order of the colors is BGR rather than RGB.

Comment: @Zvika to be clear it's OpenCV that expects BGR, not PIL.

Comment: This is only half the answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55319979/16852041

Comment: What if you want to use a [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormaps-py) to map the values of a single-channel array to colors?

Answer (score 273):

This uses PIL, but maybe some might find it useful:

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('outfile.jpg', image_array)
```

**EDIT**: The current `scipy` version started to normalize all images so that min(data) become black and max(data) become white. This is unwanted if the data should be exact grey levels or exact RGB channels. The solution:

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.toimage(image_array, cmin=0.0, cmax=...).save('outfile.jpg')
```

Comment: imsave lives in .../scipy/misc/pilutil.py which uses PIL

Comment: Be careful when converting to jpg since it is lossy and so you may not be able to recover the exact data used to generate the image.

Comment: The code gives me the error "'module' object has no attribute 'misc'". Writing `import scipy.misc` it works.

Comment: You need to make sure you have `PIL` installed, which you can achieve by `pip install Pillow` since PIL isn't directly available as a package. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip)

Comment: This is now deprecated in scipy 0.19 use - scipy.io.imwrite

Comment: @g.stevo : There were discussions around imwrite but I don't think it has been implemented!

Comment: "imsave is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0" ([Scipy 1.1.0 doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html))

Comment: this uses PIL, which is python 2 only I think?

Comment: scipy.misc.imsave is deprecated. use import imageio; imageio.imwrite('file_name.jpg', nmupy_array)

Comment: Will this overwrite an already existing file with the same name?

Comment: Maybe you should explain a little bit better the parameters `cmin` and `cmax`, which are a bit unclear from the documentation.

Comment: My version of scipy does not seem to have `toimage()` any more.

Comment: It has been deprecated

Answer (score 136):

With `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.image

matplotlib.image.imsave('name.png', array)
```

Works with matplotlib 1.3.1, I don't know about lower version. From the docstring:

```
Arguments:
  *fname*:
    A string containing a path to a filename, or a Python file-like object.
    If *format* is *None* and *fname* is a string, the output
    format is deduced from the extension of the filename.
  *arr*:
    An MxN (luminance), MxNx3 (RGB) or MxNx4 (RGBA) array.
```

[image]

Comment: Using this. But suffering from memory leak

Comment: matplotlib.imsave() in newer versions

Comment: It's `matplotlib.pyplot.imsave` in matplotlib 2+

Comment: This is what worked for me :) (everything else above needed PIL, which was python 2 only)

Comment: @HughPerkins try [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) as PIL replacement in Python 3

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then `plt.imsave('name.png', array)`

Answer (score 93):

There's `opencv` for python ([documentation here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce)).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = ... # Your image as a numpy array 

cv2.imwrite("filename.png", img)
```

useful if you need to do more processing other than saving.

Comment: Why array of size 10? What led to the choice of 10 used in this solution?

Comment: @Gathide Just as an example of writing some arbitrary numpy matrix to file. In real life replace `np.zeros((10,10))` with your image.

Comment: How can I add something like `cmap="gray"` for when I save the image using cv2?

Comment: @Xocoatzin Broken link?

Comment: @jtlz2 Updated link.

Comment: @MonaJalal i have the same question, did you figure out a solution for that?

Answer (score 84):

Pure Python (2 & 3), a snippet without 3rd party dependencies.

This function writes compressed, true-color (4 bytes per pixel) `RGBA` PNG's.

```
def write_png(buf, width, height):
    """ buf: must be bytes or a bytearray in Python3.x,
        a regular string in Python2.x.
    """
    import zlib, struct

    # reverse the vertical line order and add null bytes at the start
    width_byte_4 = width * 4
    raw_data = b''.join(
        b'\x00' + buf[span:span + width_byte_4]
        for span in range((height - 1) * width_byte_4, -1, - width_byte_4)
    )

    def png_pack(png_tag, data):
        chunk_head = png_tag + data
        return (struct.pack("!I", len(data)) +
                chunk_head +
                struct.pack("!I", 0xFFFFFFFF & zlib.crc32(chunk_head)))

    return b''.join([
        b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n',
        png_pack(b'IHDR', struct.pack("!2I5B", width, height, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0)),
        png_pack(b'IDAT', zlib.compress(raw_data, 9)),
        png_pack(b'IEND', b'')])
```

... The data should be written directly to a file opened as binary, as in:

```
data = write_png(buf, 64, 64)
with open("my_image.png", 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(data)
```

---

- [Original source](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/bin/blender-thumbnailer.py$155)
- See also: [Rust Port from this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956995/432509)
- Example usage thanks to @Evgeni Sergeev: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034111/432509

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but could you add some comments? I don't see how this writes to a file. Do you have to write the output in a previously opened file? Thanks!

Comment: @PhilMacKay, the data just has to be written to a binary file. added comment.

Comment: Can someone specify what format the image (`buf`) is supposed to be in? It does not seem to be a numpy array...

Comment: @christianmbrodbeck, a bytearray (RGBARGBA...)

Comment: Thanks @ideasman42.  I ported this code [for use in Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62072/does-blender-have-a-method-to-a-get-png-formatted-bytearray-for-an-image-via-pyt/62218#62218).

Comment: Just for clarification: This snippet has a GPL license attached?
(My interpretation of the original source.)

Answer (score 31):

for saving a numpy array as image, U have several choices:

1) best of other: OpenCV

> ```
>  import cv2   
>  cv2.imwrite('file name with extension(like .jpg)', numpy_array)
> ```

2) Matplotlib

> ```
>   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>   plt.imsave('file name with extension(like .jpg)', numpy_array)
> ```

3) PIL

> ```
>   from PIL import Image
>   image = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
>   image.save('file name with extension(like .jpg)')
> ```

4) ...

Comment: `from PIL import Image` is a clear winner in terms of time it takes to load the module.

Answer (score 30):

If you have matplotlib, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(matrix) #Needs to be in row,col order
plt.savefig(filename)
```

This will save the plot (not the images itself). 
[image]

Comment: No, for the pyplot interface, the plt.figure() is superfluous. Also, you only need the plt.show() if you want to see a figure window as well--in this case only saving an image file was desired, so there was no need to call show().

Comment: Note that the resulting image file will contain the axes and grey area of the matlplotlib figure -- not just the pixel data.

Comment: will not work if you run you script on remote host, ssh-ing to it without graphical interface support.

Comment: If you want to show the image in a notebook you can add the following: >>"from IPython.display import Image" 
   and then >>"Image(filename=filename)"

Comment: To remove the axis: `plt.axis('off')`

Comment: How do I save the image without the plot itself?

Comment: Size of image file when saved with matplotlib's imsave is larger than when saved with either skimage.io's imsave or with scipy.misc's imsave or using PIL utility.

Answer (score 21):

`scipy.misc` gives deprecation warning about `imsave` function and suggests usage of `imageio` instead.

```
import imageio
imageio.imwrite('image_name.png', img)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use 'skimage' library in Python

Example:

```
from skimage.io import imsave
imsave('Path_to_your_folder/File_name.jpg',your_array)
```

Answer (score 15):

Addendum to @ideasman42's answer:

```
def saveAsPNG(array, filename):
    import struct
    if any([len(row) != len(array[0]) for row in array]):
        raise ValueError, "Array should have elements of equal size"

                                #First row becomes top row of image.
    flat = []; map(flat.extend, reversed(array))
                                 #Big-endian, unsigned 32-byte integer.
    buf = b''.join([struct.pack('>I', ((0xffFFff & i32)<<8)|(i32>>24) )
                    for i32 in flat])   #Rotate from ARGB to RGBA.

    data = write_png(buf, len(array[0]), len(array))
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

So you can do:

```
saveAsPNG([[0xffFF0000, 0xffFFFF00],
           [0xff00aa77, 0xff333333]], 'test_grid.png')
```

Producing `test_grid.png`:

[image: Grid of red, yellow, dark-aqua, grey]

(Transparency also works, by reducing the high byte from `0xff`.)

Answer (score 12):

For those looking for a direct fully working example:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

w,h = 200,100
img = numpy.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=numpy.uint8) # has to be unsigned bytes

img[:] = (0,0,255) # fill blue

x,y = 40,20
img[y:y+30, x:x+50] = (255,0,0) # 50x30 red box

Image.fromarray(img).convert("RGB").save("art.png") # don't need to convert
```

also, if you want high quality jpeg's
`.save(file, subsampling=0, quality=100)`

Answer (score 6):

matplotlib svn has a new function to save images as just an image -- no axes etc.  it's a very simple function to backport too, if you don't want to install svn (copied straight from image.py in matplotlib svn, removed the docstring for brevity):

```
def imsave(fname, arr, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, format=None, origin=None):
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure

    fig = Figure(figsize=arr.shape[::-1], dpi=1, frameon=False)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    fig.figimage(arr, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, origin=origin)
    fig.savefig(fname, dpi=1, format=format)
```

Answer (score 5):

The world probably doesn't need yet another package for writing a numpy array to a PNG file, but for those who can't get enough, I recently put up `numpngw` on github:

https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw

and on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw/

The only external dependency is numpy.

Here's the first example from the `examples` directory of the repository.  The essential line is simply

```
write_png('example1.png', img)
```

where `img` is a numpy array.  All the code before that line is import statements and code to create `img`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpngw import write_png


# Example 1
#
# Create an 8-bit RGB image.

img = np.zeros((80, 128, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

grad = np.linspace(0, 255, img.shape[1])

img[:16, :, :] = 127
img[16:32, :, 0] = grad
img[32:48, :, 1] = grad[::-1]
img[48:64, :, 2] = grad
img[64:, :, :] = 127

write_png('example1.png', img)
```

Here's the PNG file that it creates:

[image: example1.png]

Also, I used `numpngw.write_apng` to create the animations in [Voronoi diagram in Manhattan metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950324/voronoi-diagram-in-manhattan-metric/69650264#69650264).

Comment: I am curious, how is your lib different from the others? Is it faster? Does it have fancy features?

Comment: A few features: (1) It uses numpy arrays.  (2) It is written using just python and numpy, so it does not require a C library to be installed.  (3) It can create animated PNG files. (4) It provides a class for writing matplotlib animations as animated PNG files.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be curious how it compares against https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174800/981933 in terms of performance which is also pure python. The former method is above 2x faster than PIL, which is pretty awesome. Nevermind if that's not your goal :)

Answer (score 5):

[Imageio](https://imageio.github.io/) is a Python library that provides an easy interface to read and write a wide range of image data, including animated images, video, volumetric data, and scientific formats. It is cross-platform, runs on Python 2.7 and 3.4+, and is easy to install.

This is example for grayscale image:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

# data is numpy array with grayscale value for each pixel.
data = np.array([70,80,82,72,58,58,60,63,54,58,60,48,89,115,121,119])

# 16 pixels can be converted into square of 4x4 or 2x8 or 8x2
data = data.reshape((4, 4)).astype('uint8')

# save image
imageio.imwrite('pic.jpg', data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a grayscale image:

```
im = Image.new('L', (width, height))
im.putdata(an_array.flatten().tolist())
im.save("image.tiff")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the folowing answer has the methods as proposed by @Nima Farhadi in time measurement.

**The fastest is CV2** , but it's important to change colors order from RGB to BGR. The simples is matplotlib.

It's important to assure, that the array have unsigned integer format uint8/16/32.

Code:

```
#Matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imsave('c_plt.png', c.astype(np.uint8))

#PIL
from PIL import Image
image = Image.fromarray(c.astype(np.uint8))
image.save('c_pil.png')


#CV2, OpenCV
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('c_cv2.png', cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [Py]Qt already, you may be interested in [qimage2ndarray](http://hmeine.github.io/qimage2ndarray/).  Starting with version 1.4 (just released), PySide is supported as well, and there will be a tiny `imsave(filename, array)` function similar to scipy's, but using Qt instead of PIL.  With 1.3, just use something like the following:

```
qImage = array2qimage(image, normalize = False) # create QImage from ndarray
success = qImage.save(filename) # use Qt's image IO functions for saving PNG/JPG/..
```

(Another advantage of 1.4 is that it is a pure python solution, which makes this even more lightweight.)

Comment: The 1.4 release is out now. :-)  (I edited the answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv2.imwrite`.

```
import cv2
assert mat.shape[2] == 1 or mat.shape[2] == 3, 'the third dim should be channel'
cv2.imwrite(path, mat) # note the form of data should be height - width - channel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in python environment Spyder, then it cannot get more easier than to just right click the array in variable explorer, and then choose Show Image option.

[image]

This will ask you to save image to dsik, mostly in PNG format.

PIL library will not be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With pygame

so this should work as I tested (you have to have pygame installed if you do not have pygame install it by using pip -> pip install pygame (that sometimes does not work so in that case you will have to download the wheel or sth but that you can look up on google)):

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((128, 128))
pygame.surfarray.blit_array(win, yourarray)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.image.save(win, 'yourfilename.png')
```

just remember to change display width and height according to your array

here is an example, run this code:

```
import pygame
from numpy import zeros


pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((128, 128))
striped = zeros((128, 128, 3))
striped[:] = (255, 0, 0)
striped[:, ::3] = (0, 255, 255)
pygame.surfarray.blit_array(win, striped)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.image.save(win, 'yourfilename.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I attach an simple routine to convert a npy to an image.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib

img = np.load('flair1_slice75.npy')

matplotlib.image.imsave("G1_flair_75.jpeg", img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for converting your Npy data into an image by using the PIL python library as this library mainly deal with images as well as here, I've used numpy to load the image format in the context of the dataset:

```
#importing the libraries
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.load('/kaggle/input/objects-dataset/nmbu.npy')
im = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
#saving the image from the npy format
im.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Comment: Very nice way to convert properly

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ideasman42's answer and Evgeni Sergeev's addendum, here is an implementation to convert numpy arrays to images.

Note: this implementation puts `a[1,1,:]` in the top left of the image

To demystify the png format, I pasted some info from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

this implementation displays:

- nxm arrays using a palette and scaling the values
- nxmx3 RGB arrays with one transparency color; ignores palette
- nxmx4 RGBA arrays; ignores palette and transparent color

it returns a byte string that can be passed to a PhotoImage. Its not a rigorous as Warren Weckesser' writepng below, but it gets the data into tkinter in a transparent manner.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image
# http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html
# we insist on
#  o values between 0-1
#  o g, ga, rgb, rgba
#  o nxmx 1/2/3/3
import numpy as np
import zlib, struct

def topngbytes(a:np.ndarray,transparentcolor=[1,2,3],hicolor=[255,95,0]):
    sz = a.shape
    lensz=len(sz)
    height,width=sz[0:2]
    colortype=0
    palette=None

    # Color    Allowed    Interpretation
    #    Type    Bit Depths
    #
    #    0       1,2,4,8,16  Each pixel is a grayscale sample.
    #    2       8,16        Each pixel is an R,G,B triple.
    #    3       1,2,4,8     Each pixel is a palette index;
    #                        a PLTE chunk must appear.
    #    4       8,16        Each pixel is a grayscale sample,
    #                        followed by an alpha sample.
    #    6       8,16        Each pixel is an R,G,B triple,
    #                        followed by an alpha sample.
    if lensz==2:
        colortype=3        # 8bit palette
        amin=np.min(a)
        da=np.max(a)-amin
        if da==0: a=a*0+127
        elif da<72 or da>255: a=255/da*(a-amin)

        cmin = np.array(transparentcolor,dtype=float)  # generate a two tone palette
        dc = hicolor - cmin
        palette = np.zeros(shape=(256, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        for i, r in enumerate(palette): r[:] = cmin + dc/255. * i
            
    elif lensz==3:
        n=sz[-1]                    #color info always the last dimension
        if n==2: colortype=4        # grey+alpha
        elif n==3: colortype=2      # rgb
        elif n==4: colortype=6      # rgba
        else: raise(ValueError(f"mImg: color dimension must be nxmx 1,2,3 or 4, not {sz}"))

    buf = b''.join( b'\x00' + row.tobytes() for row in a.astype(dtype=np.uint8))


    def png_pack(png_tag, data):
        chunk_head = png_tag + data
        return  struct.pack("!I", len(data)) + \
                chunk_head + \
                struct.pack("!I", 0xFFFFFFFF & zlib.crc32(chunk_head))

    # first chunc is    IHDR
    # Width:              4 bytes
    # Height:             4 bytes
    # Bit depth:          1 byte  --> we use 8  = 0-255
    # Color type:         1 byte
    # Compression method: 1 byte
    # Filter method:      1 byte
    # Interlace method:   1 byte

    # The PLTE chunk contains from 1 to 256 palette entries, each a three-byte series of the form:
    #
    # Red:   1 byte (0 = black, 255 = red)
    # Green: 1 byte (0 = black, 255 = green)
    # Blue:  1 byte (0 = black, 255 = blue)
    # The number of entries is determined from the chunk length. A chunk length not divisible by 3 is an error.
    #
    # This chunk must appear for color type 3, and can appear for color types 2 and 6;
    # it must not appear for color types 0 and 4. If this chunk does appear, it must precede the first IDAT chunk.
    # There must not be more than one PLTE chunk.
    #
    # For color type 3 (indexed color), the PLTE chunk is required.
    # The first entry in PLTE is referenced by pixel value 0

    IHDR=png_pack(b'IHDR', struct.pack("!2I5B", width, height, 8, colortype, 0, 0, 0))
    PLTE = b'' if (colortype in [0,4]) or palette is None else png_pack(b'PLTE',palette.tobytes())
    t=transparentcolor
    tRNS = png_pack(b'tRNS', struct.pack("!6B", t[0], 0, t[1], 0, t[2], 0))
    IDAT = png_pack(b'IDAT', zlib.compress(buf, 9))
    IEND = png_pack(b'IEND', b'')

    return b''.join([b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n',IHDR,PLTE,tRNS,IDAT,IEND])
```