# Image.fromarray changes size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have data that I want to store into an image. I created an image with width 100 and height 28, my matrix has the same shape. When I use `Image.fromarray(matrix)` the shape changes:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('L', (100, 28))
tmp = Image.fromarray(matrix)
print(matrix.shape) # (100, 28)
print(tmp.size) # (28, 100)
img.paste(tmp, (0, 0, 100, 28) # ValueError: images do not match
```

When I use `img.paste(tmp, (0, 0))` the object is pasted into the image, but the part starting with the x value 28 is missing.

Why does the dimension change?

Answer (score 3):

PIL and numpy have different indexing systems. `matrix[a, b]` gives you the point at x position b, and y position a, but `img.getpixel((a, b))` gives you the point at x position *a*, and y position *b*. As a result of this, when you are converting between numpy and PIL matrices, they switch their dimensions. To fix this, you could take the transpose (`matrix.transpose()`) of the matrix.
Here's what's happening:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('L', (100, 28))
img.putpixel((5, 3), 17)

matrix = np.array(img)

print matrix[5, 3] #This returns 0 

print matrix[3, 5] #This returns 17

matrix = matrix.transpose()
print matrix[5, 3] #This returns 17

print matrix[3, 5] #This returns 0
```

Comment: when your array has 3 dimension like an RGB image, then this transpose() method will change it like this (3, 28, 100) which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy and PIL have different indexing systems. So a (100, 28) numpy array will be interpreted as an image with width 28 and height 100.

If you want a 28x100 image, then you should swap the dimensions for your image instantiation.

```
img = Image.new('L', (28, 100))
```

If you want a 100x28 image, then you should transpose the numpy array.

```
tmp = Image.fromarray(matrix.transpose())
```

More generally, if you're working with RGB, you can use [transpose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) to only swap the first two axes.

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((100, 28, 3))
>>> arr.shape
(100, 28, 3)
>>> arr.transpose(1, 0, 2).shape
(28, 100, 3)
```