# Tkinter: format RGB values into string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter (and Python) and I would like to find the most efficient way to format RGB values into a string so it can be used with the `PhotoImage.put()` function.

Let's say I have a Numpy rank 3 array in which the RGB values are stored, the 3rd dimension having a length of 3 for red, green and blue respectively. The most intuitive way to proceed would be:

```
for i in range(0, n_pixels_x):
    for j in range(0, n_pixels_y):
        hexcode = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (array[i,j,0], array[i,j,1], array[i,j,2])
        img.put(hexcode, (j,i))
```

Unfortunately, this is way too slow for large images.

As described in the [PhotoImage Wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage), it is possible to pass one large string to `put()` so the function is called only once. Then, I need to efficiently convert my array into such a string, which should be formatted like this (for a 4x2 image):

```
"{#ff0000 #ff0000 #ff0000 #ff0000} {#ff0000 #ff0000 #ff0000 #ff0000}"
```

Again, this could easily be done with nested for loops, but I would like to avoid them for efficiency reasons. Is there any way to use `join()` in order to do what I want?

If needed, I can store the content of my array differently, the only constraint being that I should be able to modify the color values easily.

**Edit:** After working on this a bit, I found a way to format my values approximately 10 times faster than by using nested loops. Here is the commented piece of code:

```
# 1. Create RGB array
array = np.zeros((n_pixels_x*n_pixels_y, 3))
array = np.asarray(array, dtype = "uint32")
array[1,:] = [0, 100, 255]

# 2. Create a format string
fmt_str = "{" + " ".join(["#%06x"]*n_pixels_x) + "}"
fmt_str = " ".join([fmt_str]*n_pixels_y)

# 3. Convert RGB values to hex
array_hex = (array[:,0]<<16) + (array[:,1]<<8) + array[:,2]

# 4. Format array
img_str = fmt_str % tuple(array_hex)
```

For a 640x480 array, steps 3 and 4 take ~0.1s to execute on my laptop (evaluated with `timeit.default_timer()`). Using nested loops, it takes between 0.9s and 1.0s.

I would still like to reduce the computation time, but I'm not sure if any improvement is still possible at this point.

Comment: The inefficiency comes from the fact that python uses strings to pass data to the Tkinter engine.  I had the same problem before and was not able to find a faster way to transmit pixels to a `PhotoImage`.  The only optimisation I can think of is to use `#f00` instead of `#ff0000` (if possible for all your pixels).  This is not much.  If you really need speed (e.g. for animation), you can have a look at `pygame`.

Comment: @SciProg I was actually trying to avoid `pygame` so I could code myself almost everything I need, and `Tkinter` seemed to be a good compromise. Can `PhotoImage` accept anything other than string data? Maybe I could use the Python Image Library to process my array, but I'm not familiar with it yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find a faster way to put pixels in a PhotoImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find another way to format my array, and this really seems to be the quickest solution. The solution is to simply use `Image` and `ImageTk` to generate an image object directly from the array:

```
array = np.zeros((height, width, 3), 'uint8')

imageObject = Image.fromarray(array)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = imageObject, mode = 'RGB'))
```

This takes approximately 0.02s to run, which is good enough for my needs, and there is no need to use the `put()` function.

I actually found this answer from another question: [How do I convert a numpy array to (and display) an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image)