# Image conversion and re-creation gives cryptic result

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing

So I wrote this little code to try to convert `RGB` imge to `Grayscale` taken from this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image). The problem, is that it shows a cryptic image with no likeness to original even when I am just re-creating the original. What do you think is the problem and how should we go about solving it? Also then I want to convert it to `Grayscale` as per the given array `b`.

Here's my code:

```html
import matplotlib.image as img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = img.imread('hCeFA.png')

a = a * 255         #Matplotlib gives float values between 0-1

b = a * np.array([0.3, 0.59, 0.11])
b = np.sum(b, axis = 2) / 3           #Grayscale conversion

img1 = Image.fromarray(a, 'RGB')
img1.save('my.png')
img1.show()                     #Gives a cryptic image

plt.imshow(a/255, interpolation='nearest')     #Works fine
plt.show()
```

Comment: What makes you think `b = a * np.array([0.3, 0.59, 0.11])` is grayscale conversion, and why are you doing nothing with `b`?

Comment: @user2357112  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/grayscale_to_rgb_conversion.htm

Comment: That tutorial says to multiply the individual color channel values by those factors and *add the results together* to determine the grayscale value.

Comment: @user2357112 if the original image shows cryptic values how can grayscale image have any different outcome, i have tried that already and it has given me the same outcome..anyways i updated the question

Comment: Again, why are you not actually using `b` for anything?

Comment: @user2357112 like i said i am unable to recreate the 'original' image...and so i am asking how to do that and then convert it into grayscale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Read the image with the 'I'. 
Like 
`imread('imageName.imgFormat',"I")`
That will resolve the issue. It will read image in uint8 format, which i think you desire.

Comment: But i converted to uint8 by multiplying with 255, why doesnt it work?

Comment: You think you have converted it to uint8 by multiplying. But you didn't. To convert to uint8 you have to change the type of your container also.  ``` a = a.astype(np.uint8) ```

Comment: What do you mean by container...The dtype?

Comment: ``` a = a.astype(np.uint8) ```