# Converting numpy array image to same format as requests.get

Tags: python, image, numpy, encoding, python-requests

I have a http endpoint that wants me to send images in this format:

```
url = 'https://example_image_url.jpg'
img_bytes = requests.get(url).content
endpoint.predict(img_bytes)
```

If I have an image in the format of a numpy array, how can I convert it to be identical to the above `img_bytes` format?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to convert pixel values in a numpy array to an image.  It seems that `Image` class in the `PIL` module as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image) should do the trick. Since you haven't specified the values or the size of your numpy array, I cannot suggest whether to use RGB, Grayscale or some other conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I expected, just needed `.tobytes()`