# Using cv2.imshow to display a numpy array of np.int32

Tags: python, opencv

I have a numpy array with `shape (617, 767), dtype = int32`. Max value in the array is 164, min value in the array is -166. When I use `cv2.imshow` to show this array like an image I get this error:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'
```

I understand that `cv2.imshow` converts negative values to 0 before showing an array like an image. Then why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is the dtype of your numpy array, not the negative values. Try using uint8 or float32

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image), you can use `PIL` library.

- Convert your array to image using `fromarray` function.

For instance:

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image

# data is your numpy array with shape (617, 767)
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')

# Display with opencv
cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```