# Convert tf.Tensor to numpy array and than save it as image in without eager_execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My OC is big sur for apple M1, therefore my tensorflow version is 2.4 which has been installed from official apple github repo(https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos). When i use code bellow, i get tensor(<tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0' shape=(1, 2880, 4320, 3) dtype=float32>)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.compiler.mlcompute import mlcompute
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()
mlcompute.set_mlc_device(device_name='gpu') # Available options are 'cpu', 'gpu', and 'any'.
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)
print(tf.executing_eagerly())

image = np.asarray(Image.open('/Users/alex26/Downloads/face.jpg'))
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)

model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/captain-pool/esrgan-tf2/1")
sr = model(image) #<tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0' shape=(1, 2880, 4320, 3)dtype=float32>
```

**How to get image from sr Tensor?**

Answer (score 0):

To create an numpy array from a tensorflow tensor  you can use `make_ndarray' : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray

`make_ndarray` takes proto tensor as argument so you have to convert the tensor into a proto tensor first

`proto_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(a)  # convert tensor a to a proto tensor`

( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tensorflow-how-to-create-a-tensorproto/ )

[Convert a tensor to numpy array in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

the tensor has to be if shape `(img_height, img_width, 3)`, the `3` if you want to generate an RGB image (3 channels), see the following code to convert an numpy aaray to an image using `PIL`

To generate an image from the numpy array then you can use `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) : [How do I convert a numpy array to (and display) an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img_w, img_h = 200, 200
data = np.zeros((img_h, img_w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)  <- zero np_array depth 3 for RGB
data[100, 100] = [255, 0, 0]    <- fille array with 255,0,0 in RGB
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')    <- array to image (all black then)
img.save('test.png')
img.show()
```

source : https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-109.php

Comment: Yup, i can't convert Tensor class to numpy array, that's the main problem. I tried to use make_ndarray, but it hasn't worked.
https://pastebin.com/fhMRBN7y

Comment: say if pastebin also doesn't work for you

Comment: `make_ndarray` takes proto tensor as argument so you have to convert the tensor into a proto tensor first, i changed this above...

Answer (score 0):

If you execute eagerly it works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/captain-pool/esrgan-tf2/1")

x = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3).astype(np.float32)

image = model(x)
```

Then you can use [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/save_img) to save the resulting image. You may have to multiply the result by `255` and convert to `np.uint8` for that function to work, I'm not sure.

Comment: What is this? Please include important information here. I can't even open the link (domain blocked)

Comment: this information is big, i'll include it here if link bellow also doesn't work for you.
https://controlc.com/9bbd7a57

Comment: i don't use eagerly execution.

Comment: why are you not?

Comment: 2021-03-09 21:48:19.587997: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-03-09 21:48:19.639121: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:126] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz

Comment: https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/12
Issue about it

Comment: Solution is usage eagerly execution

Answer (score 0):

Is this the old fashioned way that you are looking after?

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(sr)
```

Comment: @Ymka Sorry, initialization was missing. What does it say now?

Comment: You might want to `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` instead to go full TF1.