# PIL: using fromarray() with binary data and writing coloured text

Tags: text, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've a basic problem with Python's library PIL. I have some .txt files containing only **0** and **1** values arranged in matrices. I have transformed the "binary" data in an image with the function **Image.fromarray()** included in PIL. The format of my data produces black&white images if I multiply it by 255, and that's fine for me. Now I want to add some text to the image, using the appropriate **text** function included in PIL, but I want that text to be **coloured**. Clearly, I can't do it because the image obtained from **fromarray** has a grayscale colormap. How can I change it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get a RGB image from a monochromatic one like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import eye                                                            
arr = (eye(200)*255).astype('uint8') # sample array
im = Image.fromarray(arr) # monochromatic image
imrgb = im.convert('RGB') # color image
imrgb.show()
```

Comment: Why not just use `im = Image.fromarray(arr).convert('RGB')`?