# write numpy ndarray to Image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read a binary file (8 bit RGB tuples) in Python, do some conversion on it and then write it as a png image. I'm doing the following:

```
typeinfo = np.dtype('>i1' ) #read single bytes
data=np.fromfile(("f%05d.txt" %(files[ctr])),dtype=typeinfo)
data=np.reshape(data,[linesperfile,resX,3]) #reshape to size/channels
```

If I display the type information of `data` it says:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(512L, 7456L, 3L)
```

Then I do some manipulation on the image (in-place), afterwards I want to write the Image to a file. Currently I use:

```
import PIL.Image as im
svimg=im.fromarray(data)
svimg.save(("im%05d"%(fileno)),"png")
```

but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
line 2026, in fromarray
raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711880/pil-using-fromarray-with-binary-data-and-writing-coloured-text? It seems that it can't handle RGB in that way.

Answer (score 57):

`Image` needs **unsigned** bytes, `i1` means **signed** bytes.  If the sign is irrelevant (all values between 0 and 127), then this will work:

```
svimg=im.fromarray(data.astype('uint8'))
```

If you need the full range 0-255, you should use `'uint8'` throughout.

Comment: This is really helpful!