# Saving a Numpy array as an image (instructions)

Tags: python, image, numpy

I found my answer in a previous post: [Saving a Numpy array as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image).  The only problem being, there isn't much instruction on using the PyPNG module.

There are only a few examples online--
http://packages.python.org/pypng/ex.html#numpy
http://nullege.com/codes/search/png.Writer.write

But what do I do in light of .write errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/png.py", line 638, in write
    nrows = self.write_passes(outfile, rows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/png.py", line 783, in write_passes
    extend(row)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/png.py", line 780, in <lambda>
    return lambda sl: f(map(int, sl))
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Here's where the error happens in my code, PCA_tool.py (The error comes after "folder.write(outfilename, PrincipalComponent"):

```
#PrincipalComponent.save(path+'transform_'+str(each)+'.png', format='PNG')
outfilename = open(str(path)+'transformed/transform_'+str(each)+'.png', 'wb')
folder = png.Writer(m,n,greyscale=True)
folder.write(outfilename, PrincipalComponent)
outfilename.close()

sys.exit(0)
```

I'm trying to save a 8400 element numpy.ndarray as a n=80 column, m=105 row greyscale png image.

Thanks,

Comment: PIL, for all it's problems, is at least more widely used, and therefore a bit better supported. http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ You'd probably be better off just doing any rescaling you need to (e.g. rescale and convert to `uint8`) and then `Image.fromarray(data).save('whatever.png')`

Comment: I should say, PrincipalComponent is of numpy.ndarray type and not a list.  I can rescale the array using PrincipalComponent.reshape(row,col), but conversion of a numpy.ndarray into a writable image file?

Comment: That's (a `numpy.ndarray`) what `Image.fromarray` expects, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might be better off using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((100,100))

#Rescale to 0-255 and convert to uint8
rescaled = (255.0 / data.max() * (data - data.min())).astype(np.uint8)

im = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
im.save('test.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe!  The image files are reading out as expected.

Comment: how will u do the same if your data is 3 dimensiona data into rgb format

Comment: how can save this variable as an image file on server?

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.imshow(np.random.random(100, 100))
plt.savefig('')
```

Comment: Hello, consider adding an explanation of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: this doesn't work as expected as it include the matplotlib frame

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to use scipy for it.

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
# x is the array you want to save 
imsave("image.png", x)
```

Full documentation is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html