# CSV to image in python

Tags: python, image, csv

I want to create an image out of an csv data.

I am reading the csv with:

```
f = open('file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
```

From here, I want to make a grayscale image that is translating each row of numbers in the list into a line of intensities in an image file.

Not sure what would be useful but here are some details about my csv file:
using floats, columns:315, rows: 144

Thanks

Comment: By Image, do you mean a graph plot? or are you trying to render the csv table itself ?

Comment: @srj I think he means gray pixels.

Comment: You may need to convert the floats to the range 0-255 for a greyscale image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two steps:

1. convert the csv file to a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) using [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

From @Andrew on [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

2. then [save the numpy array as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.image import imread
my_data = genfromtxt('path to csv', delimiter=',')
matplotlib.image.imsave('path to save image as Ex: output.png', my_data, cmap='gray')
image_1 = imread('path to read image as Ex: output.png')
# plot raw pixel data
pyplot.imshow(image_1)
# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple solution if you just want to get an impression of what the image would look like you can use the [pgm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) format.

You can create it by writing out the pixels as ascii. The link goes into more detail but the gist is that you have a file of the format:

```
P2 //which format it is
width height //dimensions
maxValue //the highest value a pixel can have (represents white)
a b c ... //the pixel values (new line needed at the end of each row)
```

How you get the values out of the CSV should be straightforward, then you could use a function like (untested):

```
def toFile(array, filename):
    f = file(filename, 'w')
    f.write("P2\n%d %d\n255\n" %(len(array[1]), len(array))
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            f.write("%d " %(j))
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try with glob.glob, what should help

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import cv2
import csv
```

Libraries ⬆️; You know what⬇️

```
image_list = []

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\your path to\file*.png'):    # '*' will count files each by one
    
    #Read
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    flattened = img.flatten() 
    print(flattened) # recommend to avoid duplicates, see files and so on.

    #Save
    with open('output2.csv', 'ab') as f: #ab is set 
            np.savetxt(f, flattened, delimiter=",")
```

Cheers

Also, find an easier method that is making **fast and not weight** image/csv

```
image_list = []
with open('train_train_.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter ='-')

    for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\your path to\file*.png'):

        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        image_list.append(img)
        csv_writer.writerow(img)
        print(img)
```