# How to make 2d images with PyPNG with 2D Python Lists

Tags: python, pypng

So reading the readme, I expected the following code:

```
import png
R = 10
G = 255
B = 0
color = [[ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ],
         [ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ]]

png.from_array(color, 'RGB').save("small_smiley.png")
```

to output a 2x3 image.

However, I get assertion errors (no description provided).

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to convert a 2D python list into an image file that's easier than messing with PyPNG?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyPNG's `from_array` doesn't support 3 dimensional matrices.

From the source comment for `from_array`:

> The use of the term *3-dimensional* is for marketing purposes
>   only.  It doesn't actually work.  Please bear with us.  Meanwhile
>   enjoy the complimentary snacks (on request) and please use a
>   2-dimensional array.

Instead, consider the Numpy/PIL/OpenCV approaches [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image).

---

**Edit:** The following code works, using numpy and Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image  # Pillow
import numpy as np     # numpy

R = 10
G = 255
B = 0
color = [[ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ],
         [ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ]]

img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(color, dtype=np.uint8))
img.save('small_smiley.png')
```

Comment: Is there no way to go from using pure python lists to PNG?

Comment: @dcheng there is, there are a list of alternatives on the the other question I linked in my answer.  I'll also edit this answer to show you how you could use numpy and pillow to create your PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

With PyPNG's [recent release](https://github.com/drj11/pypng#release-0018) your code now works!