# Adapting working code for Python 3 produces a blank PNG

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, png

I am using the following code coming (with very little modifications) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image). This script simply takes an array of hex color and writes a PNG image out of it. I am trying to adapt it to Py3 but something is going wrong.

```
import zlib, struct

def png_pack(png_tag, data):
    chunk_head = png_tag + data
    return (struct.pack("!I", len(data)) +
            chunk_head +
            struct.pack("!I", 0xFFFFFFFF & zlib.crc32(chunk_head)))

def write_png(buf, width, height):

    # reverse the vertical line order and add null bytes at the start
    width_byte_4 = width * 4
    raw_data = b''.join(b'\x00' + buf[span:span + width_byte_4]
                        for span in range((height - 1) * width * 4, -1, - width_byte_4))

    return b''.join([
        b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n',
        png_pack(b'IHDR', struct.pack("!2I5B", width, height, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0)),
        png_pack(b'IDAT', zlib.compress(raw_data, 9)),
        png_pack(b'IEND', b'')])


def saveAsPNG(array, filename):
    import struct
    if any([len(row) != len(array[0]) for row in array]):
        raise ValueError("Array should have elements of equal size")

    #First row becomes top row of image.
    flat = []
    map(flat.extend, reversed(array))
    #Big-endian, unsigned 32-byte integer.
    buf = b''.join([struct.pack('>I', ((0xffFFff & i32)<<8)|(i32>>24) )
                    for i32 in flat])   #Rotate from ARGB to RGBA.
    #print(type(buf))
    data = write_png(buf, len(array[0]), len(array))
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()


saveAsPNG([[0xffFF0000, 0xffFFFF00],
           [0xff00aa77, 0xff333333]], 'test.png')
```

It works perfectly with Python 2.7 and run without raising any error on Python 3. However the resulting image is empty... I cannot figure out what's the problem. I tried to substitute `map` with `starmap` but nothing changed. I have checked that `buf` is `bytes` instead of `string`, and it is. I really don't know why it doesn't write the file correctly.
Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2, `map` returns a list. In Python3, [`map` returns a map object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(type(map(flat.extend, reversed(array))))
# <class 'map'>
```

The map object is an iterator. It does not call `flat.extend` until it is iterated over. Since no variable is used to save the map object, it is discarded, and `flat` remains an empty list.

So instead you need:

```
flat = []
for item in reversed(array):
    flat.extend(item)
```

or a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
flat = [item for arr in reversed(array) for item in arr]
```

or [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools as IT
flat = IT.chain.from_iterable(reversed(array))
```

---

**`map` should never be used for its side-effects**. It should only be used for generating a list in Python2, or an iterator in Python3.

In Python2 using `map` for its side-effects was a frowned-upon practice. In Python3, that policy is "enforced" to some degree by making `map` an iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something trivial. I will definitely remember about map next time.