# Viewing .npy images

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

How can I view images stored with a `.npy` extension and save my own files in that format?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`.npy` is the file extension for numpy arrays - you can read them using [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
import numpy as np

img_array = np.load('filename.npy')
```

One of the easiest ways to view them is using matplotlib's [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) function:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

You could also use [PIL or pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.fromarray(img_array)
# this might fail if `img_array` contains a data type that is not supported by PIL,
# in which case you could try casting it to a different dtype e.g.:
# im = Image.fromarray(img_array.astype(np.uint8))

im.show()
```

These functions aren't part of the Python standard library, so you may need to install matplotlib and/or PIL/pillow if you haven't already. I'm also assuming that the files are either 2D `[rows, cols]` (black and white)  or 3D `[rows, cols, rgb(a)]` (color) arrays of pixel values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ali_m. In my case I inspect the npy file to check how many images was in the file with:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
data = np.load('imgs.npy')

data.shape
```

then I plotted the images in a loop:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

for i in range(len(data)):
  plt.imshow(data[i], cmap='gray')
  plt.show()
```