# Using Spyder / Python to Open .npy File

Tags: python, file, numpy

Sorry. I'm just now learning Python and everything there is to do with data analysis.

How on earth do I open a .npy file with Spyder? Or do I have to use another program? I'm using a Mac, if that is at all relevant.

Comment: `npy` files are read with `np.load`.

Comment: so like, np.load("file name")?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480297/viewing-npy-images

Answer (score 53):

`*.npy` files are binary files to store numpy arrays. They
are created with

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
np.save('data.npy', data)
```

And read in like

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('data.npy')
```

Comment: i tried importing it, it says `No such file or directory: `

Comment: That might be a question of your working directory vs. the location of the file.

Comment: The `.npy` file is in a folder with the python file. So it could likely be due to the directory. I can see if i can do anything about it.

Answer (score 7):

Given that you asked for Spyder, you need to do two things to import those files:

1. Select the pane called `Variable Explorer`
2. Press the import button (shown below), select your `.npy` file and present `Ok`.

   [image: import button]

Then you can work with that file in your current Python or IPython console.

Comment: That's the answer!!

Answer (score 3):

`.npy` files are binary files.
Do not try to open it with Spyder or any text editor; what you see may not make sense to you.

Instead, load the `.npy` file using the `numpy` module (reference: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Code sample:

First, import numpy. If you do not have it, install (here's how: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

Let's set a random numpy array as variable `array`.

```
>>> array = np.random.randint(1,5,10)
>>> print array
[2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 3]
```

To export to `.npy` file, use `np.save(FILENAME, OBJECT)` where `OBJECT = array`

```
>>> np.save('test.npy', array)
```

You can load the `.npy` file using `np.load(FILENAME)`

```
>>> array_loaded = np.load('test.npy')
```

Let's compare the original `array` vs the one loaded from file (`array_loaded`)

```
>>> print 'Loaded:  ', array_loaded
Loaded:   [2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 3]

>>> print 'Original:', array
Original: [2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 3]
```

Comment: so would i use the numpy module off of the terminal or ipython?

Comment: You can do either terminal or IPython/Jupyter notebook. The IPython notebook can do almost anything you can do in terminal but has many useful features. I'd highly recommend the notebooks over terminal when using Python. This is a good intro ti IPython if you need it: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/ipython-a-short-introduction

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import glob


for filename in glob.glob("*.*"):
    if '.npy' in filename:
        img_array = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        img_name = filename+".png"
        matplotlib.image.imsave(img_name, img_array)
        print(filename)
```

creates a png file for each image in the current directory that is of the format .npy. For example, I have this RGB image 
[image]
and its depth image is in .npy format. Converting it to png gives me so:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use the full path of the `.npy` file. For example,

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('/home/user/npyfolder/npyfile.npy')
print(data)
# Or Either save it to the text file or something.
```

I was also having the path issue, but When I changed the path from relative to an absolute path, It worked.!

Answer (score 0):

keeping it simple here. Could also save the str to a txt file

`arr = str(list(np.load("file_name.npy")))`

`print(arr)`