# Trying to use some python from a post on here, getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, png, bitwise-operators

I wish I could ask this question in context, but I don't have enough rep to comment and ask my question there, so I have to make a new post.
I am trying to use the code from this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034111/432509

I am working in Python in Houdini at school, so I am limited on what libraries I can utilize to what they have installed, so I was going to use the pure python implementation to write some data out as a PNG map, but I am running into an error in this line:

```
def saveAsPNG(array, f):
    import struct
    if any([len(row) != len(array[0]) for row in array]):
        raise ValueError, "Array should have elements of equal size"

                            #First row becomes top row of image.
    flat = []; map(flat.extend, reversed(array))
                             #Big-endian, unsigned 32-byte integer.

    buf = b''.join([struct.pack('>I', ((0xffFFff & i32)<<8)|(i32>>24) )
               for i32 in flat])   #Rotate from ARGB to RGBA.

    data = write_png(buf, len(array[0]), len(array))
    #f = open(filename, 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'

Unfortunately I am not familiar with all of this syntax and as such I am not able to repair the error myself.  Any clues?

Comment: It looks like `i32` is a  `str`, not a number... which means that your `flat` iterable has some strings it in...

Comment: What does `flat` look like?

Comment: @mgilson ok, now that I am looking over the code, yes, they are being formatted as strings, but how do I convert them into the right format?  Can I just use hex()?

Comment: @adalast -- `hex` will give you a string.  You probably want `int`.

Comment: Does your `array` contain numerical values?

Comment: @mgilson the format that he gave is in the format 0x########, which i currently have as a string.  can I just use int() on that?

Comment: @Adalast -- I think you can (setting the base to 16).  e.g. `int('0x555', 16)`

Comment: @mgilson thank you thank you thank you thank you... that worked for fixing that error, but it doesn't seem to be writing anything to the file.  I am getting a blank map file, even though I know that the data is going into my array right.