# How can I generate a proper MNIST image?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mnist

Hey guys so I've been working on a tensorflow project and I want to take a took at the test images from the MNIST database. Below is the gist of my code for converting the original data(ubyte?) into 2d numpy:

```
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot = True)
def gen_image(arr):
   two_d = np.reshape(arr, (28, 28))
   img = Image.fromarray(two_d, 'L')
   return img

batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.test.next_batch(1)
gen_image(batch_xs[0]).show()
```

However when the img gets shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrA8c.png), it looks nothing like a normal number so I figure I must have messed up somewhere, but can't pinpoint it other than when the numpy array gets reshaped to [28, 28] from [784]. Any clues?

EDIT: So apparently if I use matplotlib instead of PIL it works fine:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow - Show image from MNIST DataSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308378/tensorflow-show-image-from-mnist-dataset)

Comment: I read that post but it doesn't really explain how my image doesn't look like a number?

Comment: Hmm so apparently if I use matplotlib instead of PIL the images will show correctly... I wonder why. Anyways I'll use matplotlib for the momen

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the data by 255 and convert to np.uint8 [(uint8 for mode 'L')](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html) have it work.

```
def gen_image(arr):
    two_d = (np.reshape(arr, (28, 28)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    img = Image.fromarray(two_d, 'L')
    return img
```

[This answer helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967471/4234910)