# How can I get a binary image from a probability map in a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I have the following heat map (probability map) of an object. 
[image]
How can I convert this heatmap to a binary image? I want to take the maximum area of the object to increase the intersection with the image in the right side.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use matplotlib's [`savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)...

Answer (score 0):

To binarize, compare against a threshold:

```
thresh = 0.5
bin_map = prob_map > thresh
```

From there you can use a very large variety of solutions:

[Saving a numpy array as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image)

I recommend this one from migas:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(A)
im.save("your_file.jpeg")
```