# Convert 8 bit image to 24 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I am trying to convert my grayscale image (8 bit) to 24 bit with python.
And I tried to do it with numpy.

But how do i save it as a .png image?

```
import numpy as np
img = np.array(NewGrayScaleImage, dtype=np.uint16) 
img *= 384 #256 for 16 bit
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/902774/8881141

Comment: Many thanks. I have been looking for it for so long