# convert ndarray object to Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a gray scale image of `type uint16`, `size = (256,256)` `ndarray object`

I want to use PIL to resize it to (75,75) but it requires the input to be of Image type.

How can I convert `image of ndarray object` into `Image` type to use `image.resize((75,75), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

NOTE:
I know I can `read` image using `Image.open` if it is saved, but my `image is obtained after some image processing steps and is not read from disk`

UPDATE:
I am trying to provide image that I have :

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('image.png', box_img)
```

[image]

```
# read this similar format image of type ndarray    
image = scipy.ndimage.imread('image.png')
# convert it to Image type
```

The `image` attached when read of similar type as I need.
I need to convert this `image` into `Image` type

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your `ndarray`?

Comment: Would any of these help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# An array of ones for example
img_array = np.ones((256,256), dtype='uint16')
img = Image.fromarray(img_array)
img = img.resize((75,75))
```

Comment: I tried `img = img.resize((75,75), Image.ANTIALIAS)` and it gives error saying : `image has wrong mode`

Comment: Best used with the package `pillow` ;-)