# imageio generates black image sequence

Tags: python, animated-gif, python-imageio

I am trying to write an image sequence into gif file with *imageio*, but I am getting just a black image.

The code I am using:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

m=np.zeros((5,5))

for i in range(5):
    m[i,3]=1
    with imageio.get_writer('test.gif', mode='I') as writer:
        writer.append_data(m.astype(np.uint8))
```

I expect a growing white line..

P.S. I want the append to be inside the loop. I will use this for quite heavy image sequence, so I want to write-in on the fly

Comment: Can you check if the file is actually getting written each time? Try adding a delay in the loop and opening the files

Comment: Well, if I run this script in debug mode in PyCharm, the file only gets created after the loop is over. If the file was already there it is not updated, as far, as I understand.

Comment: As you are using numpy I would suggest you to take a look at this link. I think you can the same result using matplotlib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image

Comment: So far I could not find a way to append an image directly to .gif file. Storing all sequence in a list gets heavy on my computer (not for this simple test code, but for real data, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Create the writer method before the loop not inside it. Using the append_data method you can append an image to the gif file, as long as the resolution is the same you should be fine.