# Open (flattened) png images stored in a .parquet file format

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, parquet

I have instructions for a file format which contains `.png` images as

**Each parquet file contains tens of thousands of `137x236` grayscale images.Each row in the parquet files contains an `image_id` column, and the flattened image**

I've opened these using python and can visualise using  matplotlib's `imshow`. Can anyone suggest me any method to save these in a directory  as `.png` using python?

**I can not download any other dependencies and packages**

I have used

```
ima = pandas.read_parquet(path_of_file)
ima.shape
>>(50210, 32333)

ima.head(2)
>>
   image_id      0     1    ...  32330  32331

0  Train_50210  246    253  ...    251    250   
1  Train_50211  250    245  ...    241    244
```

Comment: Possible solution can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image/19174800

Answer (score 1):

For a non-flattened data something like this could work:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

index = 0
table = pq.read_table('data.parquet')
for img in table['image']:
    b = img['bytes'].as_py()
    with open(f'{index}.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b)
        index+=1
```

as_py() returns array of bytes

In your case you will have to collect the array manually from flattened data, iterating through each column and then dumping it straight into a png file using write() in binary mode 'wb'