# how do i create an image using a matrix with pycharm and python?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to create some pixelart using a matrix in pycharm. The problem is that I have never used this program. It's supposed to work just by simply selecting if you're working with the RGB model, but it doesn't.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
pixels = ([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
    ([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])
([0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0])
([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0])
print (pixels[2][4])
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a Numpy array as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save `pixels` as a numpy array with type `uint8` and then let `cv2` display it. If you pass `0` to `waitKey` the window will stay open until you close it manually.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pixels = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]], np.uint8)

cv2.imshow("My Image", pixels)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pillow library.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels = np.array(pixels).astype(np.uint8) # converts pixels to a numpy array

image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

# now you can save your image using

image.save('newimage.png')
```