# How to read an image and that image copy to another directory?

Tags: python, opencv

I read an image with OpenCV for processing and copy that image to another directory folder. But I get following error. How can solve this and can copy it perfectly?

```
    image_file = os.path.join("<ROOT_PATH>", file_)
    image = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image = np.stack([image]*3, axis=-1)  # make image 3-channel
    crop_img = image[int(ymin):int(ymax), int(xmin):int(xmax)]
    plt.imshow(crop_img)
    shutil.copy2(crop_img, "<dst_folder>")
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: I believe you should just use cv2 save function rather than shutil, since you are 'cropping' the image which makes it a new image rather than just copying the file from A to B. If you were just planning to copy the image, you need to pass the source path rather than crop_img

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil` copies file objects directly. Specifically, `copy2` will copy the contents of a file directly, which can be in string, bytes, or os.PathLike form. Since you are modifying the image with opencv, and you have the numpy form, it might be easier to just call `imsave`:

```py
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("<dst_folder>", os.path.basename("<ROOT_PATH>")), crop_img)
```